# Alternate of win32 framework for windowing system on windows

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, interface

I want to develop a custom window system in c++ that should not depend on win32 library. As an example, Google Chrome has an interface that is not similar to windows own interface. Similarly MPCstar and adobe products have their own interfaces. Please help me where to start for such a project?

Comment: All windowing systems on current versions Windows ultimately rely on Win32. You have lots of answers listing GUI toolkits, but I think you want to write your own rather than use Qt, wxWidgets etc. Is that right?

Comment: Nope... I will use if there is an existing one... as told by others, i will explore QT and WXWidgets... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt is awesome even if you don't need cross platform support. I assure you after using it you won't understand how anyone could ever develop native GUI on frameworks like Win32 and MFC. Its only shortcoming is the size of the DLLs you'll have to distribute with your app.

BTW is C++ a prerequisite? if not, and you only need windows, use .Net.

Comment: are QT based apps heavier than win32 based? And how much is the difference?

Comment: Since Qt is an external library, and Win32 is native, most Windows machine don't have the Qt DLLs available, so you'll need to distributed them with your installer. The overhead is about 4MB IIRC after zipping the installer. The app itself will consume a bit more ram, but IMHO it's worth the cost these days.

Answer (score 4):

You can use cross platform

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/)

or

[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)

but in my opinion Qt is better.

Comment: Both depend on the Win32 library.

Comment: Can you tell me a GUI Framework runs on Windows and doesn't depend on Win32

Answer (score 0):

I believe Qt should do the trick. I've never used it myself but it is platform independent. I know a few applications that use it, and it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29) and [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) are the better options. And since its **GUI** I think Qt performs better and has greater support and lots of libraries.

Find [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) here!