# Is there a cross-platform library for windows manipulation?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, winapi, cross-platform

Is there a library which has equivalents for WinAPI `FindWindow`,`EnumWindows`, `WindowFromPoint`, `ChildWindowFromPoint`, `GetWindowRect`, `GetWindowText`, `EnumDisplayMonitors` etc. supported on each platform: Windows, X11, OS X, ... ?

There are XGetWindowProperty , XFetchName, etc. functions on Linux, NSWindowList, CGSGetWindowProperty(), etc. on Mac. I just want a wrapper library like an abstraction layer for these functions, so I can use the same code on all platforms.

Comment: No there is not, because these functions don't make sense on all platforms

Comment: Why do not make sense?

Comment: Because each platform has it's own UI architecture, "Window" is for Windows only and these functions are part of Windows API, other platforms have their own APIs.

Comment: Guys, you just dissapoint me. There are `XGetWindowProperty` , `XFetchName`, etc. functions on Linux, `NSWindowList`, `CGSGetWindowProperty()`, etc.  on Mac. I just wanted a wrapper library like an abstraction layer for these functions, so I can use the same code on all platforms.

Comment: Use [Qt](http://qt.io/). If some feature is not wrapped in Qt, consider that it does not exist .... There is no reason that all the functions you dream of are available on all platforms.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838114/alternate-of-win32-framework-for-windowing-system-on-windows/9838163#9838163

Answer (score 4):

Those functions are windows platform specific only. You can't use them on other operating systems as they use libraries and dll files which run on Windows based systems only. However if you want to make cross platform apps using c/c++, you should consider API's like qt or gtk. 
They have functions which will run on most platforms without any changes.

Comment: Please read my question carefully

Comment: I have read your question and no such wrapper exist which would map exactly these functions onto other OS's. You would need to use some API which wraps similar functions from all OS and give you a common function name to use, code once deploy everywhere.